# Setting Values from application.properties When Building

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I found that I can set properties when running an application with `bootRun`, but I would like to set the properties when building it.

Let's say I have a variable in `application.properties` and I want to set its value on build time.

`application.properties`:

`spring.datasource.url=${db}`

If I set `bootRun { systemProperties = System.properties }` in `build.gradle`, I can pass values to `application.properties` with `./gradlew bootRun -Ddb=foo`

Is it possible to do this action on build time? I basically changed `bootRun` from `bootRun { systemProperties = System.properties }` to `build`, but I got an error:

> Could not set unknown property 'systemProperties' for task ... of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask

How can I pass values to `application.properties` on build time?

The reason why we want to pass them on build time is that we may restart projects a couple of times while we can build once. We don't want to set them each time we restart the projects. That's why we want to set them on build time.

Comment: you can use spring profiles !

Comment: @AbdelghaniRoussi, true, but we do not want to keep any environment files for dev, qa, etc on the server. That's why we are willing to pass variables on build time.

Answer (score 0):

Working example [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/master/egg_StackOverflow_64662549) of a home-grown solution (if I understand the question).

Consider a template file such as `src/main/resources/template.application.properties`:

```
server.port=__SERVER_PORT
spring.datasource.url=__SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
```

and then do perform token substitution, as part of the `build` task, to generate `src/main/resources/application.properties`:

```
build.doFirst {
    def appPropsFilename = "${projectDir}/src/main/resources/application.properties"
    ant.delete(file: appPropsFilename)
    def appProps = new File(appPropsFilename)
    def templateAppProps = new File("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/template.application.properties")

    appProps.withWriter { def writer ->
        templateAppProps.eachLine { def line ->
            def newLine = line.replace("__SERVER_PORT", "6161") 
                              .replace("__SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL", "http://example.com/db")
            writer.write(newLine + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Note the tokens are just examples. They can be named whatever you like, and the values can originate from wherever is convenient for your needs.

Also note: you'll want to test this thoroughly for your use-case. Right now, it depends on the `build` task executing. (It may be better to put the substitution code in its own task.)

Comment: Thanks, Michael. This is what I was looking for, but is it possible not to delete `application.properties`at all? It may be causing problems when working locally. Is it possible to change only those 2 values without deleting the file?